# Display the number of clustered markers exactly

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

When I have a cluster 17, 18, it shows "10+", "20+". How can I display the exact number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MyClusterItemRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyClusterItem> {

    private final IconGenerator mIconGenerator;
    private final ShapeDrawable mColoredCircleBackground;
    private final float mDensity;

    private SparseArray<BitmapDescriptor> mIcons = new SparseArray();

    public MyClusterItemRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<MyClusterItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
        mIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(context);
        mColoredCircleBackground = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

        SquareTextView squareTextView = new SquareTextView(context);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(-2, -2);
        squareTextView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        squareTextView.setId(com.google.maps.android.R.id.text);
        int twelveDpi = (int)(12.0F * this.mDensity);
        squareTextView.setPadding(twelveDpi, twelveDpi, twelveDpi, twelveDpi);
        this.mIconGenerator.setContentView(squareTextView);

        mIconGenerator.setTextAppearance(com.google.maps.android.R.style.ClusterIcon_TextAppearance);

        ShapeDrawable outline = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        outline.getPaint().setColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        LayerDrawable background = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[]{outline, this.mColoredCircleBackground});
        int strokeWidth = (int) (this.mDensity * 3.0F);
        background.setLayerInset(1, strokeWidth, strokeWidth, strokeWidth, strokeWidth);
        mIconGenerator.setBackground(background);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterRendered(Cluster<MyClusterItem> cluster, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        int bucket = this.getBucket(cluster);
        BitmapDescriptor descriptor = (BitmapDescriptor)this.mIcons.get(bucket);
        if(descriptor == null) {
            this.mColoredCircleBackground.getPaint().setColor(this.getColor(bucket));
            descriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(this.mIconGenerator.makeIcon(String.valueOf(cluster.getSize())));
            this.mIcons.put(bucket, descriptor);
        }

        markerOptions.icon(descriptor);
    }
}
```

on activity:

```
clusterManager.setRenderer(new MyClusterItemRenderer(getApplicationContext(), mGoogleMap, clusterManager));
```

Answer (score 3):

Google Map by default provide approximate number of clustered items. To achieve exact number of clustered item, just override these two methods in your custom cluster renderer class:

```
 @Override
    protected String getClusterText(int bucket) {
        return String.valueOf(bucket);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getBucket(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize();
    }
```

The complete code snippet is :

```
public class MarkerClusterRenderer extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    MarkerClusterRenderer(Context context, GoogleMap map, ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        // use this to make your change to the marker option
        // for the marker before it gets render on the map
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_pins));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, Marker marker) {
       //set marker title, tag, snippet, e.t.c here

    }

    @Override
    protected String getClusterText(int bucket) {
        return String.valueOf(bucket);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getBucket(Cluster<MyItem> cluster) {
        return cluster.getSize();
    }
}
```

**Here is the result :**

[image: Exact clustered item number : 14 instead of 10+]

**Happy Coding :)**

Comment: **Do you how to change cluster group icon colors?** Like your icon color is red but i want to change in green or whatever color which i want.

Comment: Please override the getColor method in the above custom cluster renderer class as :                                                                                               @Override
        protected int getColor(int clusterSize) {
            return Color.parseColor("#B01133"); // pass your desired color code here
        }      I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can implement ClusterRenderer to customize the rendering of the clusters. DefaultClusterRenderer provides a good base to start from. By subclassing DefaultClusterRenderer, you can override the defaults.

For an in-depth example of customization, take a look at CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity in the [demo app](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/demo/src/com/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity.java) that ships with the utility library.

[Source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility/marker-clustering#custom)

Answer (score 0):

This one is a bit old, but since it helped me find an easier solution I thought I post here.

Berdimurat has the right idea except the solution is simpler.

```
@Override
protected int getBucket(Cluster<FlagItemCluster> cluster) {
    return cluster.getSize();
}

@Override
protected String getClusterText(int bucket) {
    return String.valueOf(bucket);
}
```

Basically rather than using onBeforeClusterRendered, just alter where it gets it's data. This method also corrects that the number displayed isn't accurate because of what the getBucket logic contains.